# Determine whether the given is a rational function, a rational equation, a rational inequality or none of these.

Tags: polynomials, rational-numbers, rational-functions

1. y=5x^3-2x+1
2. 8/x-8 = x/2x-1
3. √x-2=4
4. x-1/x+1=x^2
5. $P (7x^3-4√x+1)/Q (x^2+3) $
6. 6x-5/x+3≥0

My answers:
1. Rational equation
2. Rational equation
3. None of these
4. Rational equation
5. Rational function
6. Rational inequality

Please correct me if I have any mistake. I also wonder how f(x)=6 -x+3/x^2-5 is considered a rational function, given that the denominator and numerator are not polynomials.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look up the definitions of each.  Parentheses are important, learn how to use them.  Without them, you just have a bunch of garbage.  Even better, use mathjax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I fixed it now.

Comment: 1) is a polynomial function.

Comment: Also try \frac{}{}

Comment: " I also wonder how f(x)=6 -x+3/x^2-5 is considered a rational function, given that the denominator and numerator are not polynomials." What do you mean? The denominator and numerator are both polynomials.

Comment: I am getting confused to whether the root radical in (3) is \sqrt{x} or \sqrt{x - 2}.